# Quick question regarding Stata's -xtpmg- command for dynamic panels

Tags: panel-data, vector-error-correction-model

I have a balanced panel data of N= 42 countries and T=24 years. My dependent variable and my main independent var ($X_1$) are I(1) and cointegrated. I have two more control variables: $X_2$ which is I(1) and not-cointegrated with the dependent variable and $X_3$ that is I(0).

My question is: I'm not sure whether all independent variables should enter both long-run and the short-run model specifications, i.e.,

```
xtpmg d.y d.X1 d.X2 d.X3, lr(l.y X1 X2 X3) replace pmg
```

or if $X_3$ (the stationary variable) should appear only in the long-run specification, i.e.,

```
xtpmg d.y d.X1 d.X2, lr(l.y X1 X2 X3) replace pmg
```

or neither of the above specifications?